# Force "Save As File" Option When Sharing File From Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

When sharing a mov file from Ubuntu One (See sample URL http://ubuntuone.com/2tmgfbyPMAURzYDraoMo7e ), then opening the file from your web browser such as Firefox, rather than giving you the save as file option it will start streaming the movie file instead. If sharing with friends or family & if the file is large, you don't want to be streaming the file as it may take some time.

Is there a way of forcing the "save as file" option so the user has the option of saving the file to a directory or streaming the file? Other files such zip or pdf do prompt the option. I know I could zip the file but it would be easier if you didn't have to as you won't know which files you share will behave in that manner without testing it.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of next Wednesday (or Tuesday afternoon, depending on where you are in the world) when the change gets deployed you can add `?attachment=true` to any public URL to have it delivered with content-type: attachment. So for example if your public URL as given by the system is `http://ubuntuone.com/2tmgfbyPMAURzYDraoMo7e`, if you need to force it to be delivered as an attachment you specify `http://ubuntuone.com/2tmgfbyPMAURzYDraoMo7e?attachment=true`.

Hope this helps.

> Update: this is now live.

Comment: G'day Chipaca. Thank you for responding to my question. Once this change is deployed can you advise at which of the process do I add this command / statement? Is it when I publish the file from the Ubuntu one folder (Currently running 10.04) or do I go to the Ubuntu One web site & add the statement to the end of the published URL? Example http://ubuntuone.com/2tmgfbyPMAURzYDraoMo7e/?attachment=true ? If you could post the steps using the sample URL I supplied above (To better understand), that would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance. Cheers.

Comment: @muffinman I updated my answer to (I believe) address your request. If I have answered your question, could you please “accept” it? Thank you.

Comment: G'day Chipaca. I just tried it & it works a treat :). Thank you for helping me with this query as I'll be in certain case sharing files using that statement with family & friends.

Comment: Maybe in the future you might have either option when publishing from either the computer or Ubuntu One web site. Thank you once again & I hope other people find this info useful. Cheers.

Comment: We need to make it “just work” for everybody. This is just a stopgap measure for us impatient techies, while we work out the best way to do that.